# Is it possible to make a property update other nodes like a link update does?

Tags: python, node-editor

I'm trying to make neural network in Blender nodes, and I'm currently stuck on getting the entire NodeTree to update after manually changing an input value.

[image: value wont trigger update but link will]

Is it at all possible to manually update the entire tree without pulling on a socket/updating a link?

Comment: Hey cool project. Any way to get more info about that?

Comment: @Teck-freak I gave up on using Blender and started writing my own node-based language in C++ (https://github.com/LAK132/NetworkMaker). That said, the Blender version was nearly functional and I could upload it to GitHub if there is any interest in it

Comment: There is. Definitly. :-) And thanks for the link, I'll check it out.

Comment: @Teck-freak https://github.com/LAK132/BPy-NN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I forgot to add the update parameter in the custom property:

```
#Custom properties are basically a struct, you can have any number of built in (bpy) datatypes defined here:
weight= FloatProperty(default = 1.0) #no update triggered
value = FloatProperty(default = 1.0, update=uda) #update triggered
```

Additionally the node socket needed to have it's update callback initialised

```
def init(self, context):
    self.inputs.new("SynapseSocket", "Value 1").callback(self.name, "uda")
```

For anyone else that manages to stumble across this problem, see my previous question as well: [Alternative update callback for PointerProperty?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74645/alternative-update-callback-for-pointerproperty/75110#75110)